# Why can't I see all the plugins from plugins.netbeans.org inside NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins

Is there a way I can do this?  I find it annoying having to download a plugin separately and install into NetBeans when NetBeans comes with a Plugin Manager...

Example: I'd like to install the [Path Tools](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/676/path-tools) plugin but have to download it as a zip file despite there being a plugin browser!!

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a plugin from the Plugin Portal to be seen in the plugin manager it must pass verification for the version of NetBeans that you are using. The Path Tools plugin has only been verified for version 6.0 and appears to be un-maintained.

You can read [this FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqPluginUpdateCenter) for more info.